# a puzzling filter effect using core image on OS X

Tags: macos, filter, core-image

There is a sketch filter called "CILineOverlay" in core image builtin filter. In the sample result effect showed by apple looks like that:[image]

However apple not show what detail value should be set of the parameters.

I try many many valus , but I can not get the effect apple showed. My effect just looks like that: 
[image]

Here is my code `- (IBAction)lineImg:(NSButton *)sender {

```
NSString * path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yingBW" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Cresources"];
NSImage * image=[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];


NSData * imageData = [image TIFFRepresentation];

CIImage * sourceImage = [CIImage imageWithData:imageData];

CIFilter * lineFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILineOverlay"
                                   keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey,sourceImage,
                         @"inputNRNoiseLevel",self.noiseLevel, //0.07, 0~0.1
                         @"inputNRSharpness",self.sharpness,//0.71 ,0~2
                         @"inputEdgeIntensity",self.edgeIntensity,//1.0 ,0.0~20
                         @"inputThreshold",self.threshold,//0.1 ,0~1
                         @"inputContrast",self.contrast,// 50 ,0.25~200
                         nil];

CIImage * resultimg=[lineFilter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];


NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:resultimg];

NSData *pngdata = [rep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
self.imgView.image=[[NSImage alloc] initWithData:pngdata];
```

}
`

**Is anyone can make the same effect looks like apple provide?**

Comment: Here is My demo code :https://www.dropbox.com/s/t2r98vqhpjtx7lk/SketchImg.zip?dl=0

Comment: Here is the apple developer website about CILineOverlay :https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CILineOverlay

Comment: Looks like Apple sketch came from a higher resolution version of the image the one you are using.